Dipy - Attribute Error: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'
I'm using the Dipy library and when I was attempting to import one of the functions I got this Attribute Error:
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecationshttps://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

However I don't see any use of np.float anywhere in the traceback or in my code base.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 15
     12 import matplotlib.pylab as plt
     13 import dataframe_image as dfi
---> 15 from data.nifti_dataset import resample_nifti
     16 # from data.base_dataset import _roll2center_crop
     17 # from fpdf import FPDF
     18 # from IPython import display
   (...)
     27 # from utils import metrics
     28 # from utils import myocardial_strain

File /data/__init__.py:4
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import nibabel as nib
----> 4 from dipy.align.reslice import reslice
      7 def resample_nifti(nifti, order=1, mode='nearest',
      8                    in_plane_resolution_mm=1.25, slice_thickness_mm=None, number_of_slices=None):
     10     resolution = np.array(nifti.header.get_zooms()[:3] + (1,))

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/align/__init__.py:27
     16 VerbosityLevels = Bunch(NONE=0, STATUS=1, DIAGNOSE=2, DEBUG=3)
     17 r""" VerbosityLevels
     18 This enum defines the four levels of verbosity we use in the align
     19 module.
   (...)
     24 DEBUG : print as much information as possible to isolate the cause of a bug.
     25 """
---> 27 from dipy.align._public import (syn_registration, register_dwi_to_template, # noqa
     28                                 write_mapping, read_mapping, resample,
     29                                 center_of_mass, translation, rigid, affine,
     30                                 affine_registration, register_series,
     31                                 register_dwi_series, streamline_registration)
     33 __all__ = ["syn_registration", "register_dwi_to_template",
     34            "write_mapping", "read_mapping", "resample",
     35            "center_of_mass", "translation", "rigid", "affine",
     36            "affine_registration", "register_series",
     37            "register_dwi_series", "streamline_registration"]

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/align/_public.py:26
     16 from dipy.align.imaffine import (transform_centers_of_mass,
     17                                  AffineMap,
     18                                  MutualInformationMetric,
     19                                  AffineRegistration)
     21 from dipy.align.transforms import (TranslationTransform3D,
     22                                    RigidTransform3D,
     23                                    AffineTransform3D)
---> 26 import dipy.core.gradients as dpg
     27 import  as dpd
     28 from dipy.align.streamlinear import StreamlineLinearRegistration

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/core/gradients.py:10
      8 from dipy.core.onetime import auto_attr
      9 from dipy.core.geometry import vector_norm, vec2vec_rotmat
---> 10 from dipy.core.sphere import disperse_charges, HemiSphere
     12 from dipy.utils.deprecator import deprecate_with_version
     15 WATER_GYROMAGNETIC_RATIO = 267.513e6  # 1/(sT)

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/core/sphere.py:776
    774 unit_octahedron = Sphere(xyz=octahedron_vertices, faces=octahedron_faces)
    775 unit_icosahedron = Sphere(xyz=icosahedron_vertices, faces=icosahedron_faces)
--> 776 hemi_icosahedron = HemiSphere.from_sphere(unit_icosahedron)

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/core/sphere.py:342, in HemiSphere.from_sphere(klass, sphere, tol)
    339 u/classmethod
    340 def from_sphere(klass, sphere, tol=1e-5):
    341     """Create instance from a Sphere"""
--> 342     return klass(theta=sphere.theta, phi=sphere.phi,
    343                  edges=sphere.edges, faces=sphere.faces, tol=tol)

File lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/core/sphere.py:328, in HemiSphere.__init__(self, x, y, z, theta, phi, xyz, faces, edges, tol)
    325 """Create a HemiSphere from points"""
    327 sphere = Sphere(x=x, y=y, z=z, theta=theta, phi=phi, xyz=xyz)
--> 328 uniq_vertices, mapping = remove_similar_vertices(sphere.vertices, tol,
    329                                                  return_mapping=True)
    330 uniq_vertices *= 1 - 2*(uniq_vertices[:, -1:] < 0)
    331 if faces is not None:

File dipy/reconst/recspeed.pyx:97, in dipy.reconst.recspeed.remove_similar_vertices()

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:305, in __getattr__(attr)
    300     warnings.warn(
    301         f"In the future `np.{attr}` will be defined as the "
    302         "corresponding NumPy scalar.", FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)
    304 if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 305     raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    307 # Importing Tester requires importing all of UnitTest which is not a
    308 # cheap import Since it is mainly used in test suits, we lazy import it
    309 # here to save on the order of 10 ms of import time for most users
    310 #
    311 # The previous way Tester was imported also had a side effect of adding
    312 # the full `numpy.testing` namespace
    313 if attr == 'testing':
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 15
     12 import matplotlib.pylab as plt
     13 import dataframe_image as dfi
---> 15 from data.nifti_dataset import resample_nifti
     16 # from data.base_dataset import _roll2center_crop
     17 # from fpdf import FPDF
     18 # from IPython import display
   (...)
     27 # from utils import metrics
     28 # from utils import myocardial_strain

File /data/__init__.py:4
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import nibabel as nib
----> 4 from dipy.align.reslice import reslice
      7 def resample_nifti(nifti, order=1, mode='nearest',
      8                    in_plane_resolution_mm=1.25, slice_thickness_mm=None, number_of_slices=None):
     10     resolution = np.array(nifti.header.get_zooms()[:3] + (1,))

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/align/__init__.py:27
     16 VerbosityLevels = Bunch(NONE=0, STATUS=1, DIAGNOSE=2, DEBUG=3)
     17 r""" VerbosityLevels
     18 This enum defines the four levels of verbosity we use in the align
     19 module.
   (...)
     24 DEBUG : print as much information as possible to isolate the cause of a bug.
     25 """
---> 27 from dipy.align._public import (syn_registration, register_dwi_to_template, # noqa
     28                                 write_mapping, read_mapping, resample,
     29                                 center_of_mass, translation, rigid, affine,
     30                                 affine_registration, register_series,
     31                                 register_dwi_series, streamline_registration)
     33 __all__ = ["syn_registration", "register_dwi_to_template",
     34            "write_mapping", "read_mapping", "resample",
     35            "center_of_mass", "translation", "rigid", "affine",
     36            "affine_registration", "register_series",
     37            "register_dwi_series", "streamline_registration"]

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/align/_public.py:26
     16 from dipy.align.imaffine import (transform_centers_of_mass,
     17                                  AffineMap,
     18                                  MutualInformationMetric,
     19                                  AffineRegistration)
     21 from dipy.align.transforms import (TranslationTransform3D,
     22                                    RigidTransform3D,
     23                                    AffineTransform3D)
---> 26 import dipy.core.gradients as dpg
     27 import  as dpd
     28 from dipy.align.streamlinear import StreamlineLinearRegistration

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/core/gradients.py:10
      8 from dipy.core.onetime import auto_attr
      9 from dipy.core.geometry import vector_norm, vec2vec_rotmat
---> 10 from dipy.core.sphere import disperse_charges, HemiSphere
     12 from dipy.utils.deprecator import deprecate_with_version
     15 WATER_GYROMAGNETIC_RATIO = 267.513e6  # 1/(sT)

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/core/sphere.py:776
    774 unit_octahedron = Sphere(xyz=octahedron_vertices, faces=octahedron_faces)
    775 unit_icosahedron = Sphere(xyz=icosahedron_vertices, faces=icosahedron_faces)
--> 776 hemi_icosahedron = HemiSphere.from_sphere(unit_icosahedron)

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/core/sphere.py:342, in HemiSphere.from_sphere(klass, sphere, tol)
    339 u/classmethod
    340 def from_sphere(klass, sphere, tol=1e-5):
    341     """Create instance from a Sphere"""
--> 342     return klass(theta=sphere.theta, phi=sphere.phi,
    343                  edges=sphere.edges, faces=sphere.faces, tol=tol)

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/dipy/core/sphere.py:328, in HemiSphere.__init__(self, x, y, z, theta, phi, xyz, faces, edges, tol)
    325 """Create a HemiSphere from points"""
    327 sphere = Sphere(x=x, y=y, z=z, theta=theta, phi=phi, xyz=xyz)
--> 328 uniq_vertices, mapping = remove_similar_vertices(sphere.vertices, tol,
    329                                                  return_mapping=True)
    330 uniq_vertices *= 1 - 2*(uniq_vertices[:, -1:] < 0)
    331 if faces is not None:

File dipy/reconst/recspeed.pyx:97, in dipy.reconst.recspeed.remove_similar_vertices()

File /lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:305, in __getattr__(attr)
    300     warnings.warn(
    301         f"In the future `np.{attr}` will be defined as the "
    302         "corresponding NumPy scalar.", FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)
    304 if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 305     raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    307 # Importing Tester requires importing all of UnitTest which is not a
    308 # cheap import Since it is mainly used in test suits, we lazy import it
    309 # here to save on the order of 10 ms of import time for most users
    310 #
    311 # The previous way Tester was imported also had a side effect of adding
    312 # the full `numpy.testing` namespace
    313 if attr == 'testing':dipy.datadipy.data

I attempted to search the code base using VS code and couldn't find a single use of np.float anywhere so I don't understand how this error could occur.
I am using numpy 1.24.4 and dipy 1.3.0

You are using python 3.8. But, it only supports python 3.9 or above.

https://pypi.org/project/dipy/

The current version of pip I'm using doesn't have access to 1.9.0 but I tried with 1.8.0 and that didn't fix the problem either.

What error you get for 1.8.0?  https://pypi.org/project/dipy/ says 1.9.0 was released on 9th March 2024.

Exact same error. This code is pretty old so I don't think using the latest version will help much honestly. I'm using an older version of python and and older version of pip for that exact reason.

I got the root cause. You must use python 3.9 or above according to the document.

Okay. I have no idea how this code ever ran then because it was written before python 3.9 existed. Thank you though.

This code ran before because earlier numpy versions were compatible with dipy.
